# Equivalent notations for second partial derivative of a quadratic form

Tags: calculus, matrices, partial-derivative, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I noticed this notation while going through [a tutorial](http://project.hupili.net/tutorial/hu2012-matrix-calculus/hu2012matrix-calculus.pdf) on matrix calculus:
$$ \frac{\partial x^TAx}{\partial xx^T}
   = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( \frac{\partial x^TAx}{\partial x} \right)
= A^T+A $$

I'm not sure how the first equality is established (is the partial derivative of $x^TAx$ with respect to $xx^T$ actually equal to the second partial? if so can somebody plz show me). If the first term is simply a shorthand notation, wouldn't $ \frac{\partial^2 x^TAx}{\partial x\partial x^T} $ or  $ \frac{\partial^2 x^TAx}{\partial x^2} $make more sense?

I'm aware of the notation $ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}$ in ordinary calculus, so I don't understand why the numerator and denominator of the shorthand notation above each uses only a single partial symbol...

Comment: After seeing more matrix calculus in action, I came to the conclusion that this shorthand is unfortunately just another abuse of notation. But I'd like to find out what $\frac{\partial x^TAx}{\partial xx^T}$ literally evaluates to

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in your comment, define a new variable $$M=xx^T$$Then use this new variable and the [Frobenius Inner Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product) to write the function and its differential as 
$$\eqalign{
 f &= A:M \cr
df &= A:dM \cr
}$$
Since $df=\big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial M}:dM\big),\,$ the gradient must be
$$\eqalign{
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial M} &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial (xx^T)} &= A \cr
}$$
So that's what the expression evaluates to, if taken literally.